# Warning: oci_parse(): ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated - Where? I cannot find it

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I am getting this error:

`Warning: oci_parse(): ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated in <DIRECTORY> on line 200 Warning: oci_execute() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <DIRECTORY> on line 201`

In reference to this code (line 200/201 marked):

```
        $testSQL =  "insert into INTOXDM.JOINT_USE (RECEIVED, 
                REGION, 
                PERMIT, 
                CUSTOMER, 
                TO_BUSINESS, 
                TO_PERMIT, 
                POWER_ADDRESS, 
                COMPANY, 
                MAPSECTION, 
                POLES, 
                FEE, 
                INVOICE, 
                DATE_LARRY, 
                DAYS_LARRY, 
                PI_PON, 
                DATE_PD, 
                DAYS_LARRY_PD, 
                RETURNED, 
                DAYS_PD, 
                ERRORS_PD, 
                ERRORS_MULTIPLE, 
                DATE_MAKEREADY_JU, 
                DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPLETE, 
                DAYS_MAKEREADY, 
                DAYS_JU_PROCES, 
                APPROVAL, 
                DAYS_PERMIT_IN_JU, 
                DATE_PLANNING, 
                DAYS_OPEN, 
                DATE_ROUTED, 
                DAYS_TOTAL, 
                COMMENTS) values (
                '$RECEIVED', 
                '$REGION', 
                '$PERMIT', 
                '$CUSTOMER', 
                '$TO_BUSINESS', 
                '$TO_PERMIT', 
                '$POWER_ADDRESS', 
                '$COMPANY', 
                '$MAPSECTION', 
                '$POLES', 
                '$FEES', 
                '$INVOICE', 
                '$DATE_LARRY', 
                '$DAYS_LARRY', 
                '$PI_PON', 
                '$DATE_PD', 
                '$DAYS_LARRY_PD', 
                '$RETURNED', 
                '$DAYS_PD', 
                '$ERRORS_PD', 
                '$ERRORS_MULTIPLE', 
                '$DATE_MAKEREADY_JU', 
                '$DATE_MAKEREADY_COMPLETE', 
                '$DAYS_MAKEREADY', 
                '$DAYS_JU_PROCESS', 
                '$APPROVAL', 
                '$DAYS_PERMIT_IN_JU', 
                '$DATE_PLANNING', 
                '$DAYS_OPEN', 
                '$DATE_ROUTED', 
                '$DAYS_TOTAL', 
                '$COMMENTS')";
        $testParse = oci_parse($objConnect, $testSQL); //LINE 200 
        $testExecute = oci_execute($testParse); } } //LINE 201
```

However, I cannot find what I am missing. I have been at it for an hour, it is very frustrating. Are there tools that you can post source into that assist in finding these errors?

Comment: Please don't inject random raw input into your SQL code. Use `oci_parse()` and `oci_execute()` the way they're intended, with parameters.

Comment: I'm confused why this was marked as duplicate, unless I am misunderstanding what the error means. Doesn't this mean that I missed a ' or " or ) etc in my code? I am, obviously, a novice programmer so I don't know too much.

Comment: Yes, you do have a syntax error in your SQL code, but that error happens because you compose your SQL code by concatenating variables with arbitrary contents—those variables become part of the code! That's called SQL Injection. Companies leak sensitive data now and then because of it.

Comment: If you can only read one manual, I recommend [The Underground PHP and Oracle Manual](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/php/underground-php-oracle-manual-098250.html).

Comment: Oh, alright I understand what you are saying. Thank you for teaching me the proper methods lol.. Odd how the other posts which have the exact same style of code weren't forewarned xD. All a learning process.